# Handling rapid consecutive updates in Entity Framework Core within a distributed system

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I'm experiencing an issue with Entity Framework Core in my distributed system, specifically with handling concurrent updates on a `Bill` object. My system is designed to handle updates as full replacements, but I'm encountering a problem due to Entity Framework Core's concurrency control.

**Scenario**

I have a `Bill` object with a property indicating the amount that has been paid. I've set up an API endpoint (`payBill`) which, when called, initiates an asynchronous process to calculate the remaining amount on the bill. This async process does not block the API call.

**Issue**

When I call `payBill` multiple times in quick succession (e.g., three rapid calls for testing purposes), it triggers multiple asynchronous events concurrently. My system's design can handle these concurrent updates, as the last update is expected to reflect the correct data.

However, Entity Framework Core throws a concurrency exception:

> The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s)

This seems to occur because the `Bill` object gets updated in the database between the time it's loaded and when the updated version is saved.

**Key Points**

- Rapid, successive payments on a bill is a scenario my system needs to support. Race condition updates will happen, my bill update logic is designed to handle this.
- The data row is not deleted; the discrepancy is due to the Bill object being updated by another process before the current update is saved.
- I am using a PostGres database
- I am using Entity Framework Core 8.0

**Question**

How can I configure Entity Framework Core to handle this scenario without throwing a concurrency exception? I want EF Core to allow the last update to proceed without errors, even in cases of rapid, successive updates.

Comment: You will likely need to add code demonstrating a reproducible example. The error doesn't look like optimistic concurrency checks but rather something coupled to the length of time entities might be tracked during/between operations. When it comes to race conditions and async code, you also need to address the fact that async calls will not necessarily complete in the same order that they were called, so a "last it wins" strategy may not play out the way you intend.

Comment: Consider encapsulating all database operations within a singular, serializable transaction. Alternatively, if potential phantom issues within your unit of work are not a concern, utilizing a repeatable read transaction could be a suitable solution for your case.

Comment: Look up "eventual consistency"/"journaling", especially in banking contexts. I think the first thing to do is to decouple "wanting to perform and action" from actually performing it (i.e. through a priority queue of sorts, for example). Then you can "construct" consistent state for a "Bill" from a list of transactions. I know this sounds like an XY reply ...